# urdf_tutorial Groovy vs. Fuerte

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorial, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i just installed ROS Groovy within Ubuntu 12.10 ( native (full) and virtualized (lean install) )

In both Groovy installations the tutorial "Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch" fails.

It brings NO USEFUL OUTPUT. RViz keeps an useless small window without any content.
None of the logfiles shows some kind of error.

In an freshly installed ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 the same tutorial runs immedeately as suspected.

Does somebody know what to do to bring this tutorial up and running in Groovy?
Should I keep my fingers of Groovy?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60888/urdf_tutorial-groovy-vs.-fuerte/) by [jla](https://answers.ros.org/users/4698/jla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made a .rviz version here: https://raw.github.com/DLu/robot_model_tutorials/master/urdf_tutorial/urdf.rviz

Save this file in the urdf_tutorial directory and change instances of urdf.vcg ot urdf.rviz

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rviz config file format changed between groovy and fuerte.  If you are familiar with rviz, you can recreate the config file. Basically close the rviz that is launched (a bad config file hoses it) and start a new one with rosrun rviz rviz. Add a robot model, a grid and set the fixed frame to base link. Also, please submit a bug.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3